# changing datetime format Ubuntu 22

Tags: linux, ubuntu, date, locale

Looking for a solution for changing my machine datetime format to be DD/MM/YEAR hh:mm:ss.
Currently ,Linux default is MM/DD/YEAR hh:mm:ss

This is a GCP machine , running ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS .

Thanks !

Comment: Can you give an example of where you observe this date format by default? Is it in some GUI components or on the terminal when executing certain commands?

Answer (score 2):

The date/time format of a system usually depends on the system's "locale" settings.

In Ubuntu 22.04 (maybe in previous releases, too) there is a useful tool for updating locale settings called `localectl`.

Check which locales are available on your system:

```
localectl list-locales
```

The date/time format you are describing is commonly used in the UK and so the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale should achieve that. You may find a locale more fitting for your needs in the locale list though.

The locale is a set of multiple variables, not just one global setting. In the command below, you are setting the date/time format using the `LC_TIME` locale variable. If you would like to delve into the variety of the variables further, check `locale` and `man localectl`.

*Please note that although the locales in the locale list may end with ".UTF-8", when setting individual variables, use the ".utf8" ending. (in some cases specifying ".UTF-8" does not work. I am not sure why, just my own experience)*

```
localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8
```

To apply the change, you must log out of your current session and log back in. **Warning: this will close all running applications and processes started under that session. Save everything before logging out if needed.** To log out:

```
gnome-session-quit --no-prompt
```

You can verify your locale settings with these two commands:

```
locale
localectl status
```